# owl-carousel does not works (js not load)

Tags: javascript, angular, owl-carousel

I'm trying to add owl-carousel slider to my angular 7 project
the problem is that owl.carousel.js not load

i already added it to angular.json -> script[]
but does not work

here is my angular.json-> script

```
"scripts": [
              "src/assets/ltr/js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js",
              "src/assets/ltr/js/bootstrap.min.js",
              "src/assets/ltr/js/themejs/libs.js",
              "src/assets/social-js/card.js",
              "src/assets/ltr/js/unveil/jquery.unveil.js",
              "src/assets/ltr/js/countdown/jquery.countdown.min.js",
              "src/assets/ltr/js/dcjqaccordion/jquery.dcjqaccordion.2.8.min.js",
              "src/assets/ltr/js/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js",
              "src/assets/ltr/js/bootstrap-notify.min.js",
              "src/assets/ltr/js/themejs/application.js",
              "src/assets/ltr/js/themejs/homepage.js",
              "src/assets/ltr/js/themejs/so_megamenu.js",
              "src/assets/ltr/js/themejs/toppanel.js",
              "src/assets/ltr/js/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js",
              "src/assets/ltr/js/crypto-js/CryptoJS.js"
            ]
```

and component.html

```
  <div id="so-slideshow">
    <div class="module slideshow--home8 no-margin" >
      <!-- <app-carousel [source]="sliderData" [imageDefault]="'1920x550.jpg'"></app-carousel> -->
      <div class="item">
        <a href="#"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1490077476659-095159692ab5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80" alt="slider1" class="img-responsive"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <a href="#"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1490077476659-095159692ab5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80" alt="slider1" class="img-responsive"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <a href="#"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1490077476659-095159692ab5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80" alt="slider1" class="img-responsive"></a>
      </div>
      <!--<div class="loadeding"></div>-->
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

it shows like this

[image]

it must be like this

[image]

Comment: Do you add a CSS style to the carousel?

Comment: No, but i added owl.carousel.css to angular.json -> styles

Comment: Please share a working stackBlitz demo

Answer (score 0):

Add this path in your index.html file like mentioned below if not working from angular.json:

JS path

```
<script src="assets/ltr/js/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
```

CSS path

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/ltr/css/owl.carousel.css">
```

Or either make sure your path is correct. Check it in your installed package and copy the exact path from there.

Comment: Very bad solution, dont add anyting inline in index.html